# Getting underlying thought of someone who has put bounty on old question

Tags: discussion, bounty

This is a current example, someone has placed a bounty on an old question:

[image]

[Does QGIS work with Anaconda?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119495/does-qgis-work-with-anaconda)

That's all fine, but how can you guess that person's current problem if he or she can't change/rephrase the original question (which should be avoided, imho) to adapt to his or her current situation?

One idea would be to open a new question, but then chances are high that it's getting flagged as duplicate/closed, unless a subtle explanation is given on the differences.

An other idea would be to comment on the original question, but place to fully express oneself in comments is low and proper formatting is often not possible.

So, how can we as best as we can fill this slight 'lack' in the application design for this particular situation?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @Aaron](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-do-you-get-the-underlying-thought-of-someone-who-has-put-a-bounty-on-an-old#comment11163_5265):

> There is an option to include a message in the bounty, which will be
> displayed prominently with the bounty.

In this case the message written by the person placing the bounty was:

> Offering a bounty to refresh this question to current day.  Also to
> encourage people to flesh out how to use [conda] and it's packages if
> you've installed [QGIS] the normal way, rather [than] through conda
> itself.

Also, with respect to:

> how can you guess that person's current problem if he or she can't
> change/rephrase the original question (which should be avoided, imho)
> to adapt to his or her current situation?

my understanding of SE site design is that anyone in the community, especially its author but even anonymous users (see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)), can at any time revise/change/rephrase a question *as long as those edits do not cause it to become a candidate for closure or invalidate any of the existing answers*.  The remedy for either of those italicized eventualities is rollback.

The aim is always to evolve our Q&As into each being a clear question with one or more clear answers that directly address it.  Starting bounties is one way to promote that happening but editing can be used to improve Q&As at any time in many ways.

It is fine to ask a new question if the reason it should not be a duplicate is made clear, and the community agrees, by not closing it, that the difference is sufficient to warrant a new question.

It is fine to comment but comments are temporary and intended only to seek question clarifications, so they are not intended to remain on the site indefinitely.